# How should I find which XIB contains this reference?

Tags: xcode, xib

I got this message

```
Could not load the "ItunesArtwork.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with
```

Okay which XIB contains ItunesArtwork.png?

How do I know that?

I search for ItunesArtwork.png and found nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As .xibs are just XML files, you can just search them in the finder, I guess. So just go to your projects directory, and search for "ItunesArtwork.png", then you should also get the .xib names where you used it.